# Show only single toaster if there is any error in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to react js. Here I am using `react-redux-toaster`.

Now, I have a following code .

```
else {
    dispatch({
        type: REQUEST_SUCCESSED
    })
    toastr.error("Error while Fetching the technologies,Please try again");
    if (response.status === "") {
        toastr.error('Our server is down. Please check again');
    }
    dispatch({
        type: FAILED_TEHNOLOGY_FETCHING,
        data: response.status,
    });
    if (response.status === 401) {
        toastr.error('Please Login Again');
        localStorage.clear();
        history.push('/');
    }
}
```

Now Here, I want to show only one toaster but what happens is that

when we hit request then if the server is down then it hits the request but still shows the other errors. can any one help me with this ?

How I will be able to show only one toaster ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't seem to check conditions

```js
else {
    if (!response.status) {
        toastr.error('Our server is down. Please check again');
    }
    else if (response.status === 401) {
        toastr.error('Please Login Again');
        localStorage.clear();
        history.push('/');
    }
    else if (/* not sure on condition */) {
      toastr.error("Error while Fetching the technologies,Please try again");
      dispatch({
          type: FAILED_TEHNOLOGY_FETCHING,
          data: response.status,
      });
    } else {
      dispatch({
          type: REQUEST_SUCCESSED
      })
    }    
}
```

Comment: Its when I make an api call and that api call did not response then it will call that failed

Comment: dispatch({
                            type: REQUEST_SUCCESSED
                        })
  This should be dispatched in any case

Comment: Yeah, but the idea is to call the statements conditionally